How to use GeoServer Raster Attribute Table support extension
My GeoServer version is 2.25.0,extension version:gs-rat-2.25-SNAPSHOT.jar;gt-brewer-31-SNAPSHOT.jar
I want to use an extension module for GeoServer called the Raster Attribute Table Extension. The documentation for it can be found at: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/rat/installing.html. After following the instructions to download the extension and place it in the /usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib directory,

I restarted GeoServer, but the module did not seem to take effect. When I tried to publish raster data, the corresponding Raster Attribute Table page did not appear.

I'm not sure what is causing this issue.
I have tried adjusting the log level to GEOSERVER DEVELOPER LOGGING and GEOTOOLS DEVELOPER LOGGING, but I did not see any error messages in the logs.
20240814
20240815
20240816
